# QueryStringOrHeaderApiVersionReader in my dotnet web api is not working

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I'm trying to use this code to enable API versioning in query string parameter and header. However i get an error saying "The type or namespace name 'QueryStringOrHeaderApiVersionReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Api_Versioning]" and i'm unable to figure out what exactly the issue is.

[image: code]

Comment: Did you add the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning`?

Comment: yes i have added it using the .net cli using the below command...
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning --version 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

`QueryStringOrHeaderApiVersionReader` is no longer supported.

If you need it you will have to downgrade your `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` nugget package to version `1.1`.

Refer this wiki: https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Version-Reader#query-string-or-header-api-version-reader--110-